# tikz Controlling the position of prongs of underbrackets in an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to make a two (or more) pronged underbracket (or overbracket). In particular, I would like to control the:

1. number of prongs.
2. position of the prongs by specifying to which characters in the equation they should 'point' to.
3. position of the handle (and therefore the label of the underbracket).
4. colouring of the underbracket and its label

Below is a MWE of the closest result I have obtained so far for a two-pronged underbracket below the string `nanbn` (in an equation environment), whose prongs should point to the `a` and the `b`, and is labelled by `e`.  It uses the basic tree structure in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{grow'=up}
\tikzset{level distance={16pt}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.north)--   +(0pt,2pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\newcommand{\twopf}[6]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {$#1$}
        child {node {$#2$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child {node {$#3$}}
        child {node {$#4$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child {node {$#5$}}
        child {node {$#6$} edge from parent[draw=none]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\twopf{e}{n}{a}{n}{b}{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
nanbn
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In the output Eq (1) is my attempt and Eq (2) is how I would like the characters above the underbracket to appear (i.e. no spacing between them).

[image]

The problem that remains is the appearance of spaces in Eq (1) between the arguments of the `\twopf` command.  It seems that in my approach, this is due to the value of the 'sibling distance', which is the distance between the centres of two adjacent sibling leaves.  I have looked at several questions on this subject, but I have been unsuccessful in controlling this parameter in order to get the desired effect.

I'd be grateful for any pointers as I have spent a long time getting nowhere with this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `\tikzmark` to mark the points that you want to refer to and then do the drawing separately. This allows you to separate the text from the under brackets that you desire:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand*{\TickLength}{1.0ex}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    n \tikzmark{Mark A Left} a \tikzmark{Mark N Left}n\tikzmark{Mark N Right} b\tikzmark{Mark B Right} n
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, red, thick]
    \draw  (Mark A Left.south)
        -- ++(0,-\TickLength)
        -|  (Mark B Right.south);
    \draw ($(Mark N Left.south)!0.5!(Mark N Right.south)+(0,-\TickLength)$)
        -- ++(0,-\TickLength) node [below, blue] {$e$};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```